# IF... ELSE statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me to fix the error? I'm still new with mySQL. The error is at if else statement.

```
select idpersonal,fname,lname,city from fathi.personal where city='QS';
if (fname=A%) then
begin
select idorder,order_no,item_total from fathi.order;
else 
update fathi.order 
set item_total=0
where personal.idpersonal=order.idpersonal;
```

Comment: Needs a bit more info... first off try removing "begin". I don't know much, but I don't think "fname = A%" is valid, try LIKE 'A%'

Comment: i'm attempt to update the data. can i get the code? or would you mind to share any references about mysql (books,notes,etc)?

Comment: actually, i'm trying to use the if else statement. but i don't know how to use it. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Would you mind to share any references on mySQL (incl. sample codes) with me? I really need those references. @spencer7593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF` is not a valid SQL statement in MySQL.

There's three separate statements here, a SELECT from personal, a SELECT from order (which returns all rows from the table), and an UPDATE statement that has a predicate that references a column from an unknown rowsource.

Here are some examples of SQL based on what was posted in the question.

1) return all rows from personal with city='Q5'

```
SELECT p.idpersonal
     , p.fname
     , p.lname
     , p.city
  FROM fathi.personal p 
 WHERE p.city='QS';
```

2) return all rows from order that are related to personal with city='Q5' and fname starting with 'A'. (This only returns rows from personal that are related to an order.)

```
SELECT o.idorder
     , o.order_no
     , o.item_total
     , p.idpersonal
     , p.fname
     , p.lname
     , p.city
  FROM fathi.order o 
  JOIN fathi.personal p 
    ON p.idpersonal = o.idpersonal
   AND p.city = 'Q5'
   AND p.fname LIKE 'A%' ;
```

3) Modify the contents of table "order", to set the item_total to zero, for all rows that are related to personal with city=`Q5' and have fname not starting with 'A'

```
UPDATE order o
  JOIN personal p 
    ON p.idpersonal = o.idpersonal
   AND p.city = 'Q5'
   AND (p.fname IS NULL OR p.fname NOT LIKE 'A%') ;
   SET o.item_total=0
```

Those are just examples. We're just guessing at what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. This answer inspired me to solve a problem I have